# Get previous date and time in github workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

I've seen posts about how to get the *current* time in a github workflow, however I want to get *yesterday's* date. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a custom Action like [Date Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/date-actions)
The example provided by the author looks like it does the job!

```
    - uses: ajilraju/actions-date@v0.1
  with:
    date --date='2 days ago'
```